# In python does self require any object of its same type?

Tags: python, class

I am reading 9.3.2. Class Objects from the python docs and I was hoping someone can clear up the following:

How come both scenarios return 'hello world'? The first instance I kind of understand (at least I believe I do) because self is referencing the object itself 'MyClass' and I guess passing 'm' to self in the second instance is doing the same? Does the function 'self' just need ANY reference to a 'MyClass' object?

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     """A simple example class"""
...     i = 12345
...     def f(self):
...         return 'hello world'
...
>>> MyClass.f(MyClass)
'hello world'
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> MyClass.f(m)
'hello world'
```

Comment: `self` is just an argument, anything may be passed there, not only instances of source class. It's just typically does not make any sense to do it.

Comment: For whatever reason I thought there was something unique about 'self'.  When you say its just an argument it makes sense. It will take whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Python is "duck-typed", meaning it doesn't matter *what* type `self` is, as long as it provides the correct interface. Here, `self` isn't used in the body of the function, so you could pass absolutely *anything* to `MyClass.f` and it would work.

```
>>> MyClass.f(None)
'hello world'
>>> MyClass.f(9)
'hello world'
>>> MyClass.f("foo")
'hello world'
```

Comment: This is only true in Python 3.X, in Python 2.X a `TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with MyClass instance as its first argument...` will be raised instead.

Comment: Right; I assumed Python 3 since `MyClass` did not have an explicit parent class.

Comment: Your'e right, it is indeed Python 3, otherwise the line `MyClass.f(MyClass)` would raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass.f('what the...')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-cca57c03fecc> in <module>()
----> 1 MyClass.f('what the...')

TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

mc = MyClass()

mc.f('what?')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bcd3830312d3> in <module>()
----> 1 mc.f('what?')

TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

In the first instance, the function requires an instance of `MyClass` as the first argument.  In the second, the instance is implicitly passed.  The string argument `What?` is thus a second argument to the function which is unexpected.

What you may want:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print('hello world')

>>> MyClass.f()
hello world

mc = MyClass()
>>> mc.f()
hello world
```

Comment: This is only true of Python 2.X, the first example will work fine (no `TypeError`) in Python 3.X.